# Тире или запятая? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Тире или запятая требуется в указанном месте?

**С одной стороны (?) всё прекрасно. С другой — нет.**

Comment: мне кажется, тут однозначно тире.

Answer (score 5):

Правильно:
**С одной стороны, всё прекрасно. С другой — нет.**
Или:
С одной стороны, всё прекрасно, с другой — нет.

[**С ОДНОЙ СТОРОНЫ, вводное сочетание**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_694)

Обороты с «одной стороны» и «с другой стороны» являются вводными, потому должны выделяться запятыми с двух сторон. Следует иметь в виду, что если оборот *с другой стороны* употребляется в сокращенном виде (*с другой*), то вместо запятой после него ставится тире.

*Хвастунишка, а суть-то вся: "С одной стороны, нельзя не признаться, а с другой — нельзя не сознаться!"* (Ф. Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы)

*С одной стороны, знания студента были глубокими, с другой — они оказались односторонними*.

[**Знаки препинания при вводных словах, сочетаниях слов и предложениях**](http://www.orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=291)

Comment: Думаю, что в примере из вопроса сокращение не сводится только к слову "стороны": предложение "С другой стороны, нет" выглядело бы странно (вводный оборот к простому отрицанию). Тире по-прежнему нужно было бы - чтобы обратить внимание на упрощение подразумеваемого "не всё прекрасно" до отрицания "нет".

Comment: Да, конечно: "не всё прекрасно" = "нет", тире было бы нужно и при полном обороте. Но вопрос был не об ЭТОМ тире, поэтому я привела только общее правило и похожие предложения.